# Calling a model function from a template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to override the change_form.html admin template.  As I enter data in the admin area, it would help me to see a few lines from the CSV file I'm entering data about.

So, in my copy of change_form.html, I've placed:

```
<!-- First three lines of the csv we're parsing. -->
foo: {{ csv_app.csv_sample }}
<!-- end -->
```

And in my model ("csv_profile"):

```
def csv_sample(self):
    return "foo"
```

I've tried changeing csv_app.csv_sample to parse_csv.csv_app.csv_sample as well as a bunch of other things - but I'm not getting any results.  Clearly I'm not doing this right - can anyone spot what I'm missing?

Comment: And the `csv_app` is an instance of `csv_profile`?

Comment: @limelights no -- csv_app is the app name.  csv_profile is a model.

Comment: Ummm. To access `csv_app` in the template, it must first be a variable in context and you can't call functions from specific app like that inside template. pass the function as context variable. And read Django documentation please. Doesn't seem like you have.

Comment: Try using django-debugtoolbar to discover which template variables are available to you in any template.

Comment: @Bibhas actually I have.  That's a strange assumption to make.  Sorry I'm not as good with Django and Python as you are?  Also I'm not calling the admin template directly, I'm invoking it by going to /admin.  So.. thanks but I'm not sure how to do what you're suggesting.  In fact it says in the Django documents that you can do what I'm trying - see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#accessing-method-calls - perhaps I should suggest you read the documentation.

Comment: @bouke Thanks..  I can see that it is indeed using my template vs the built-in one, which is great.  When I pull up the context I don't see what I'm looking for.  I'm not sure how to proceed - it confirms that the template doesn't have access to the model function, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Shoot, that makes perfect sense.  Thank you -- that means I need to save the record first then pull it up again in order to get the data I want.  Let me see if I can modify my code accordingly now.

Comment: @Harv, no the doc doesn't say what you're doing is possible. You confused app name with model and it's instance. Read it again please. And glad that it got solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`change_form.html` is used for both creating new objects and updating existing ones, so you need to make sure you display the field for existing objects only.

The more portable way to do this is to write a quick template tag, and then pass it the `object_id` variable from the template.

The tag could be:

```
from django import template

from csv_app.models import csv_profile

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('_tag_csv_preview.html')
def csv_preview(pk):
    csv = csv_profile.get(pk=pk)
    return {'preview': csv.csv_sample()}
```

The `_tag_csv_preview.html` template simply contains `{{ prevew }}` (or any other styling you want).

Then in `change_form.html`:

```
{% load csv_app.tags %}
{% if object_id %}
    {% csv_preview object_id %}
{% endif %}
```

You can also use another trick - which is a lot simpler. `adminform.form.instance` will represent the instance for which the form is being rendered, and you then do this:

```
{% if adminform.form.instance %}
   {{ adminform.form.instance.csv_sample }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Oooh, that last paragraph is exactly what I was trying to figure out just now.  I was thinking - there has to be an instance that I'm editing or creating, so how can I access it?  Wonderful.  I'm going to give this a shot right away.